# weired windows update and restart behaviour, iis 8 stops serving until system is restarted

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-server-2012, automatic-update, iis-8

I have a small website on windows machine with windows server 2012 and IIS 8.There are 2 network cards one has access to internet and admin can access using the external Ip. The second card is connected to wifi and office guys use it by the internal Ip. For most of the time there is no problem except (Till now 2 times) when it gets automatic update. When ever there is an update and it needs to restart it appends a line at the bottom of the login page saying restart to finish update or it will reboot in 2 days. The general behavior of us has been to ignore this message and let it do the required action automatically.

Last month the iis was not serving the pages over Wifi and I got the call from them, I was able to connect to it using remote desktop and also the site was availabe on the external IP.
but when office people were trying to connect they use to get server is taking to long to respond, also the server was giving response for ping. After trying various things restarting app-pool, shuting down and restarting web service nothing came up. After getting flustrated I told my seniors that there seems to be hardware issue please send some one to check that, Instead they packed the server and got it in office. In office it started to work and we didnt found any problem.

Yesterday also there was the same problem and incidentally it was also asking for reboot or it will reboot is 2 days. however a netword guy went there and his response was that wifi and router are working fine and there is some issue with iis. Again after whole day of brain storming  , nothing was found when I restarted the server.On restart again every thing started working.

I cannot find anything on net for this weird behavior. I know there is some problem with something but how can I pin point to that problem.

Please note that IIs continues to serve page on one lan card  but not on the other.

Comment: Seems like a race condition.  It is as if IIS is coming up before the wifi link is established, and so not listening on the wifi interface.  Does it work if you just restart iis?

Comment: Check your HTTPERR log, probably exhausting kernel memory and rejecting connections

Comment: @paul no just restarting iis didn't had any effect.

Comment: Roll back the last driver update and see if that resolves the issue.